# Android Instagram redirect url does not match error

Tags: android, instagram

I get Redirect does not match with register call back url. error code : 400 with Instagram integration with my Android application.

I have fixed the issue. I have just shared my experience with the issue and solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced Redirect url does not match error (error code :400) with Instagram integration in my application.While registering the application I have used https://www.google.co.in in  redirecting url field. Sometime the Google url or without "url/something" does not work correctly therefore I faced the redirecting issue so that I used my company url for example  http://www.xxxxxx.com/yyyy Its works.

I have referred the "https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/android-instagram-oauth" github site for my application. In the github application just leave the mCallbackUrl variable as empty in the InstagramApp class and in ApplicationData class fill the client id, client_secret and call back url what we get when register our application in Instagram developer console.

Thanks.